# Arraylist cannot be applied

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to get the password description text input to populate the array view of my app.

[image]

Unfortunately, for portion of my while(cursor.movetoNext()) say that my string cannot be applied to arraylist. I am trying to determine what to change in my updateList method to accommodate my password item.

Here is my updatelist method.

```
   private void updateList(){
           ArrayList<String> tasklist = new ArrayList<>();
           SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
           Cursor cursor = db.query( PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.TABLE, new String[]{PasswordContract.PasswordEntry._ID, PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSWORD, PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASS_DESC},
                   null, null, null, null, null);

           while (cursor.moveToNext()){
               String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSWORD));
               String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PasswordContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASS_DESC));
               tasklist.add(new PasswordItem(password, description));

if (mAdapter == null){
           mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                   R.layout.item_password,
                   R.id.password,
                   R.id.password_description,
                   tasklist);
           mPasswordListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}else{
           mAdapter.clear();
           mAdapter.addAll(String.valueOf(tasklist));
           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
       cursor.close();
       db.close();
```

I am trying to figure out how to connect my customadapter to my updatelist method.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mStringList;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> mStringList) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_password);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mStringList = mStringList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_password, parent, false);

        TextView your_first_text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password);
        TextView your_second_text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password_description);

        your_first_text_view.setText(mStringList.get(position));
        your_second_text_view.setText(mStringList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using POJO class not string so do the required changes in adapter as well as in your list type

use this

```
ArrayList<PasswordItem> tasklist = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of

```
 ArrayList<String> tasklist = new ArrayList<>();
```

plus `mAdapter` should be of `CustomAdapter` type so

declare it like `CustomAdapter mAdapter` and initialize it later as

```
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.item_password ,tasklist);
```

and in your adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PasswordItem>{
//                                              ^^^^^^^
    private Context mContext;
    private List<PasswordItem> mStringList;
    //            ^^^^^^^
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource , List<PasswordItem> mStringList) {
        super(context, resource , mStringList);
        this.mContext = context;
        //this.mStringList = new ArrayList<>(); not required 
        this.mStringList = mStringList;
    }

    public updateList(List<PasswordItem> mStringList){
         this.mStringList = mStringList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_password, parent, false);

        TextView your_first_text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password);
        TextView your_second_text_view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password_description);

        your_first_text_view.setText(mStringList.get(position).password);
       //  use your getter or field names of POJO class
        your_second_text_view.setText(mStringList.get(position).description);
        return convertView;
    }
```

and to replace this `mAdapter.addAll(String.valueOf(tasklist));` so your code will be

```
if (mAdapter == null){
       mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
               tasklist);
       mPasswordListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}else{
       mAdapter.clear();
       mAdapter.updateList(tasklist);
       // pass the new list to adapter
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Comment: Pavneet, almost there. I have added if and else statements on my updatelist method. I have updated my post to show them. The arrayadapter tells that cannot infer arguments. Do you have an idea of what causing this?

Comment: It still says arrayadapter cannot be applied.

Comment: you have answered my first question. That suffices my query. :)

Comment: Error:(120, 23) error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Error:(125, 20) error: cannot find symbol method updateList(ArrayList<PasswordItem>)

Comment: look carefully at the code inside `CustomAdapter` , it's there

Answer (score 1):

When you add items to an arraylist , they need to be the same type as the defined one. You defined arraylist with type string but add a PasswordItem object to it.
Change the arraylist type to hold PasswordItem instead:

```
ArrayList<PasswordItem> tasklist
```